# Why does 'string' + undefined => 'stringundefined'?

Tags: javascript

The question is pretty straight forward. In Javascript, why does:

```
'string' + undefined
//=> 'stringundefined'
```

I would have expected just `string` to be returned, or at least an error stating you can't convert undefined into a string data type.

Comment: It works with all datatypes, test for yourself. 'string' + true = 'stringtrue'. 'string' + [1,2] = 'string1,2' etc.

Comment: Crazy. `'string' + function myFunc() {} => 'stringfunction myFunc() {}'`.

Comment: Read through this page for all the default (forced) type conversions in javascript :  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: Crazy? A matter of opinion - and in my opinion it's not crazy. Should you be trying to concatenate things if you're not already sure that they have the data types that you need them to have?

Comment: Not crazy and pretty darn self explanatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are performing a string concatenation, **forced** type conversion occurs. `undefined` is being converted to its *string value* and added to the string

```
'string' + undefined

Step 1: 'string'
Step 2: undefined -> 'undefined'
Step 3: 'string' + 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 3):

When you concatenate strings each item gets cast to a string, and undefined becomes "undefined".

`String(undefined); // "undefined"`

Answer (score 3):

interesting question.

Because ECMAScript use internal ToString operation to convert primitives to string.

```
    undefined=> "undefined" 
    null=>"null" 
    boolean=>either "true" or "false" 
    number>the number as a string e.g. "1.765"
```

http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html